# EmberJS template is not redering model values

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ember.js

Here is my app/models/post.js (Which is the model)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  author: DS.belongsTo('author'),
  title: attr('string'),
  body: attr('string')
});
```

Here's the route which is located at the app/routes/post.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

Here's the template for handling it app/templates/post.hbs

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>by {{author.name}}</h2>

<hr>
<div class = "body">
{{body}}
</div>
```

Here is my router.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post',{ path: '/posts/:post_id'});
});
```

Whenever I access the localhost:4200/post/1 The view renders nothing, however whenever I view the network it retrieves this json data

```
{"post":{"id":1,"title":"How to win at life","body":"Body","author":1},"authors":[{"id":1,"name":"George","posts":[1,2]}]}
```

Here's my directory structure

[image]

Whenever I run my debugger and hover at the page it shows that I have a model [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `model` property in your template:

```
<h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
<h2>by {{model.author.name}}</h2>

<hr>
<div class = "body">
{{model.body}}
</div>
```

`ObjectController` is deprecated now so `model` properties aren't proxied anymore and you can't use just `{{title}}` instead of `{{model.title}}`.

`this.resource()` is also [deprecated now](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resetting-nested-route-namespace).

Comment: How come I can't access it using the attributes?

Comment: You were able to do this only by using proxying and ObjectController. ObjectController is deprecated now so you need to use full path when accessing model property.